# Android Testing using Robotium - OpenGL screenshot

Tags: android, opengl-es, robotium, android-testing

Is there a way to take a screenshot with OpenGL elements?

Answer (score 1):

This site worked like a charm for me: http://blog.javia.org/android-opengl-es-screenshot/

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see how you you use it whit in a test project. Any idea?